# Strips away all HTML tags from emails in my inbox (thunderbird)

Tags: html, email, thunderbird

Is there a plugin or hack for thunderbird that strips out all HTML tags?

For example, if I receive an email that has the following content in the body of the email:

```
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8=
"/>
    <style type=3D"text/css">
        body {
            margin:0;
            color:#333;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#006699;
        }

        p {
            margin:0px;
        }

        img {
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #title p{
            font-size:15px;
            font-family: "Our Ember", Arial, sans-serif;
        }

    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body><img width=3D"1" height=3D"1" src=3D"https://www.example.com/gp/r.html=
?C=3D1BDNQAME26BY1&M=3Durn:rtn:msg:20210814073749c3222ee107f04186b9d218a2d6=
30p0na&R=3D7KE509NKJXP3&T=3DP&U=3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-our=
.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&H=3DG774NKHTYQC3WGV9A1QIE4DWIVQA&=
ref_=3Dpe_2429110_469155610_opens" />
<table align=3D"center" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"520" cellpadding=3D"0" s=
tyle=3D"padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"520" cellpadding=3D"0" st=
yle=3D"margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right:=
 20px;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr width=3D"520">
                        <td width=3D"520" height=3D"52" style=3D"border-bot=
tom:1px solid #eaeaea; padding-top:10px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr width=3D"520">
                                    <td width=3D"107" id=3D"logo">
                                        <img id=3D"blah" alt=3D"Lo=
go Image" width=3D"107" height=3D"auto" src=3D"https://m.example.com/i=
mages/G/01/authportal/tiv/our_logologo_RGB._CB424581820_.png"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align=3D"left" valign=3D"top" style=3D"font-family: Connections, =
'Calibri', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;"><p s=
tyle=3D"font-family: Connections, 'Calibri', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; =
font-size: 16px; color: #000000; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height=
: 140%; Margin: 0; padding: 0; webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-lig=
atures; font-variant-ligatures: none;"> 
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=3D"2" align=3D"left" style=3D"text-=
align: left; font-size:17px; font-family: 'Our Ember', Arial, sans-serif=
; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right:=
 1px;"><p>Dear customer,</p></td></tr><tr>
                        <td colspan=3D"2" align=3D"left" style=3D"text-alig=
n: left; font-size:17px; font-family: 'Our Ember', Arial, sans-serif; pa=
dding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 1p=
x;"><p>Your OTP is 123456</p></td></tr>

...
```

I would want the email to be rendered as, roughly

```
    
    
    
    

    
        
            
                
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                        
                            
                    

                            Dear customer,

                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                            Your OTP is 123456


...
```

For security and privacy reasons, I disable HTML rendering in thunderbird.

While some email senders rightly define both a `Content-Type: text/html;` and `Content-Type: text/plain;` mimeparts of the email body, it's becoming increasingly popular for many businesses not to do so.

Moreover, it's becoming increasingly popular for services to send OTP codes on every login to email (setting aside the absurdity mandating an authentication credential that's sent over an insecure medium without offering something like TOTP as 2FA to their customers..)

Consequently, it's not uncommon for me to spend 90% of the time I spend trying to authenticate into a website just scrolling through hundreds of lines of css and html tables trying to find the 6-digit plaintext OTP needle in a sea of html nonsense.

Is there a very simple thunderbird plugin or hack that will not "render" the html and try to convert it to plaintext, but just very dumbly detect html tags and remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Not a Thunderbird-plugin-, but a command-line based solution:

You can also try a combination of [`xmllint`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libxml2-utils/xmllint.1.en.html) and [`xidel`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/) (a powerful xpath2 query tool):

(There are many variations of how to do this)

```
cat /tmp/example-mail.html \
 | xmllint --format --html -     \
 | xidel -e "//body" 2>/dev/null
```

will return (along with some messages such as `-:79: HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : body`)

```
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                     
                                

                            
                        
                    
                        
                            Dear customer,


                        Your OTP is 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with thunderbird, but I wrote a very simple python script to strip HTML with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

### Prereqs

On Debian, first install the python dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-bs4
```

Create the script

```
cat > fu-html.py <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print( "Enter html below:" )
html_doc = sys.stdin.readlines()

soup = BeautifulSoup( ''.join(html_doc), 'html.parser' )

print( 'Plaintext:' )
print( '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------' )
print( soup.get_text() )

EOF
chmod +x fu-html.py
```

### Example Execution

Now you can execute the script. When prompted, just paste the snippet of HTML into the terminal and press ctrl+D to send `signalEOF`.

```
root@disp7899:~# ./fu-html.py
Enter html below:
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8=
"/>
    <style type=3D"text/css">
        body {
            margin:0;
            color:#333;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#006699;
        }

        p {
            margin:0px;
        }

        img {
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #title p{
            font-size:15px;
            font-family: "Our Ember", Arial, sans-serif;
        }

    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body><img width=3D"1" height=3D"1" src=3D"https://www.example.com/gp/r.html=
?C=3D1BDNQAME26BY1&M=3Durn:rtn:msg:20210814073749c3222ee107f04186b9d218a2d6=
30p0na&R=3D7KE509NKJXP3&T=3DP&U=3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-our=
.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&H=3DG774NKHTYQC3WGV9A1QIE4DWIVQA&=
ref_=3Dpe_2429110_469155610_opens" />
<table align=3D"center" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"520" cellpadding=3D"0" s=
tyle=3D"padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"520" cellpadding=3D"0" st=
yle=3D"margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 20px; margin-right:=
 20px;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr width=3D"520">
                        <td width=3D"520" height=3D"52" style=3D"border-bot=
tom:1px solid #eaeaea; padding-top:10px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr width=3D"520">
                                    <td width=3D"107" id=3D"logo">
                                        <img id=3D"blah" alt=3D"Lo=
go Image" width=3D"107" height=3D"auto" src=3D"https://m.example.com/i=
mages/G/01/authportal/tiv/our_logologo_RGB._CB424581820_.png"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align=3D"left" valign=3D"top" style=3D"font-family: Connections, =
'Calibri', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;"><p s=
tyle=3D"font-family: Connections, 'Calibri', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; =
font-size: 16px; color: #000000; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height=
: 140%; Margin: 0; padding: 0; webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-lig=
atures; font-variant-ligatures: none;"> 
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=3D"2" align=3D"left" style=3D"text-=
align: left; font-size:17px; font-family: 'Our Ember', Arial, sans-serif=
; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right:=
 1px;"><p>Dear customer,</p></td></tr><tr>
                        <td colspan=3D"2" align=3D"left" style=3D"text-alig=
n: left; font-size:17px; font-family: 'Our Ember', Arial, sans-serif; pa=
dding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 1p=
x;"><p>Your OTP is 123456</p></td></tr>
Plaintext:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------




        body {
            margin:0;
            color:#333;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#006699;
        }

        p {
            margin:0px;
        }

        img {
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #title p{
            font-size:15px;
            font-family: "Our Ember", Arial, sans-serif;
        }

    






















Dear customer,
Your OTP is 123456

root@disp7899:~#
```

As you can see, all of the html tags (not the CSS in-between the HTML tags) is stripped away, making it *much* easier for a human to read the text contents of the email